# How to pass a parameter value to a4j:jsFunction

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

On my page I have a button that opens a list of items in a popup. When I select 1 item in the list, I want to pass the id of the item to the backingbean of my first page. Is it possible? It tried to do it with `a4j:jsFunction` and `a4j:param` but it does'nt work.

This is my code:

**page 1:**

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="renderGuarantor" render="guarantor" actionListener="#{prospectDetail.setNewGuarantor}">
  <a4j:param name="param1" assignTo="#{prospectDetail.newGuarantorId}" />  
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

**popuppage:**

```
<h:outputLink value="" onclick="window.opener.renderGuarantor(#{applicant.deposit_id});window.close();">
  <h:graphicImage style="padding:0 1px; border:0"  value="${path.staticRootUrl}images/confirm.gif"  alt="${msg.applicantslist_select}" title="${msg.applicantslist_select}"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

And this is the backing bean code for the first page

```
private Integer newGuarantorId;
public void setNewGuarantor()  {
    guarantor = newGuarantorId;
}

public Integer getNewGuarantorId() {
    return newGuarantorId;
}

public void setNewGuarantorId(Integer newGuarantorId) {
    this.newGuarantorId = newGuarantorId;
}
```

When selecting in the popup the method in my backingbean is called, but `newGuarantorId` is null and `setNewGuarantorId` is never called.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: Are you sure `#{applicant.deposit_id}` is not null in the new window?

Comment: yes it is filled in with the correct id.

Comment: Hmm.. thats strange, nothing looks wrong..Not an answer to your question but try this workaround - instead of assigning the value to `guarantorId`, keep the param as `<a4j:param name="param1"/>` and in the `actionListener` method retrieve this `param1` from the request as `String param1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("param1");`. And then convert this param to `int` and utilize it further. That should work.

Comment: Great! :) Putting it as an answer below.Please mark it, if it is the answer to your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm.. thats strange, nothing looks wrong..Not an answer to your question but try this workaround - instead of assigning the value to guarantorId, keep the param as `<a4j:param name="param1"/>` and in the `actionListener` method retrieve this param1 from the request as `String param1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().‌​get("param1");`.
And then convert this param to int and utilize it further. That should work

Answer (score 4):

Try switching from `actionListener` to `action`:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="renderGuarantor" render="guarantor" action="#{prospectDetail.setNewGuarantor}">
  <a4j:param name="param1" assignTo="#{prospectDetail.newGuarantorId}"/>  
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

Here is recommended reading on the topic: [a4j:jsFunction](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="renderGuarantor" render="guarantor" 
                actionListener="#{prospectDetail.setNewGuarantor(prospectDetail.newGuarantorId)}" />
```

And in your Managed bean, define the `setNewGuarantor` method as following:

```
public void setNewGuarantor(int newGuarantorId)  {
   guarantor = newGuarantorId;
}
```